# Datatax Cassandra not accessible from BYOH HiveServer2

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax-enterprise

I followed the instructions from Datastax to setup a BYOH environment using the following article: [Datastax BYOH](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/byoh/byohIntro.html)

So i have a Datastax Enterprise and Hortonworks Hadoop running on a node. I created a column family in Cassandra and inserted some sample data, and i was able to access and manipulate the data in Cassandra from Hive(which is running on Hortonworks Data Platform, not Datastax Enterprise).

Now, when i try to access the same Cassandra column family using the JDBC driver for HiveServer2, i am able to see the column family in the database but when i try to manipulate it, or even try to view it using SELECT query, or do a DESCRIBE query, i am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.input.HiveCqlInputFormat
```

And the same error shows up when i try to run hive without the BYOH prefix. In a nutshell, i am only able to manipulate Cassandra data from hive when i use the byoh prefix while starting hive command line interface otherwise the above error shows up.

I am not sure what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using:

Datastax Enterprise: 4.5.1

Cassandra: 2.0.8

Hive: 0.12

Answer (score 0):

This first paragraph on this page of the docs, which perhaps you didn't see, seem to say that using the byoh prefix is required to manipulate Cassandra data from Hive: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/byoh/byohUsing.html

Comment: Yes i saw it, but is there any other way to access the Cassandra data using HiveServer2? Because i am trying to use the Hive JDBC driver to write a Java function.